# How can I get XMLRPC.NET to match perl speed?

Tags: c#, c++, perl, xml-rpc

I have an `xmlrpc` server written in C++ (using `libxmlrpc++`). It provides a function `getversion()` returning a string.

- Calling it from `Perl` (using [`RPC::XML::Client`](https://metacpan.org/pod/RPC::XML::Client)), 100 calls 1.25s.
- Calling it from `C#` (`using XMLRPC.NET`), 100 calls 50.322s.

This is running on Windows7 Pro.

Any ideas what's going on, and how to fix it?

```
[XmlRpcUrl("http://localhost:9000/RPC2")]
public interface ICutControl : IXmlRpcProxy
{
  [XmlRpcMethod]
  string getversion();
}

class Program
{
  public static void do_test()
  {
    ICutControl proxy;

    proxy = XmlRpcProxyGen.Create<ICutControl>();

    int count = 100;
    try
    {
      for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
      {
        string version = proxy.getversion();
        Console.WriteLine("{0}:{1}", i, version);
      }
    }
    catch (System.Net.WebException ex)
    {
      Console.Error.WriteLine("exception: {0}", ex.Message);
    }
  }
  proxy = null;
}
```

**[Update]**

I tried compression, but it didn't make a difference. Since this seems to be happening on the client side, without restarting the server, I am out of ideas.
The perl I am using is cygwin. I add the perl below.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;
use RPC::XML;
use RPC::XML::Client;

my $url = 'http://localhost:9000/RPC2';

my $cli = RPC::XML::Client->new($url);

for (my $i = 0; $i < 100; $i++) {
  my $resp = $cli->send_request('getversion', ());
  print "version:", $resp->value, "\n";
}
```

**[Update]**

I didn't find an answer about why XMLRPC.NET is slower.

**But** by writing a C++/CLR wrapper around the libxmlrpc++ library, I did get a >100 times increase in speed.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Are you sure that the time is wasted in the RPC call? Is it maybe wasted elsewhere?

Comment: I used WireShark to look at the client requests. For XMLRPC.NET, the delay was after the reply arrived.